Error when using \cite[]{} inside theorem environment
I have a tex file
\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@article{xia2020lq,
  title={Lq (Lp)-theory of stochastic differential equations},
  author={Xia, Pengcheng and Xie, Longjie and Zhang, Xicheng and Zhao, Guohuan},
  journal={Stochastic Processes and their Applications},
  volume={130},
  number={8},
  pages={5188--5211},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem}[see e.g. \cite[aa]{xia2020lq}]
If A then B.
\end{theorem}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib}

\end{document}

The file is compiled without problem if I use \cite{xia2020lq}. The problem Argument of \NAT@@citetp has an extra } happens if I use \cite[aa]{xia2020lq}. Could you elaborate on this issue and how to solve it?

This is a FAQ: \begin{theorem}[see e.g. {\cite[aa]{xia2020lq}}]

@egreg Thank you very much for your solution.
